# How to capture mouse events on iPadOS

Tags: ios, swift, mouseevent, ipados

How do we capture mouse events on iPadOS using Swift? EX: Mouse click, scroll, move[x,y position] ,etc..

I 've seen a plenty for macOS but not for iPadOS . Can some one please help throwing some light on how to capture mouse events on iPadOS devices ?The requirement is that I will have to connect mouse to an iPad over bluetooth and I should be able to programatically track the mouse movement, click events and scroll events.

Comment: Have you read Apple's Pointer Interactions documentation? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pointer_interactions based on that it doesn't look like Apple exposes the APIs you're looking for to developers

Answer (score 0):

Mouse clicks are passed in via `touchesBegan` as a `UITouch` with a `type` of `.indirectPointer`. Add `UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents` to your `Info.plist` file to receive these.

Mouse scroll can be detected by adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with `allowedTouchTypes` set to an empty array, and maybe `allowedScrollTypesMask` set to `.all`. The event information is sent to the target and selector you assign to the gesture recognizer, the gesture state stores the trackpad state, and `translation(in view: UIView?)` provides the scroll offset.

As far as I'm aware mouse position, and therefore mouse move, cannot be captured directly.